# Joyeuses Fêtes à tous à toutes - Is this accurate french?

Tags: sens, usage

I was just given this line from a Canadian government French translation department, but I don't think that it makes sense, does it?

> Joyeuses Fêtes à tous à toutes

Translates to “Happy Holidays to all to all”, doesn't it?

---

J'ai reçu cette phrase du département de traduction du gouvernement Canadien, mais je ne suis pas certain qu'elle soit correcte, l'est-elle ?

> Joyeuses Fêtes à tous à toutes

La traduction serait « *Happy Holidays to all to all* », n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Merci pour la traduction Evpok.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Joyeuses Fêtes à toutes et à tous

ou, plus naturellement

> Joyeuses Fêtes à tous et toutes

ou plus simplement (puisque le masculin l'emporte)

> Joyeuses Fêtes à tous

Comment: Oui. Merci à toutes et à tous. :)

Comment: Pour le gouvernement fédéral canadien, il faut habituellement garder les deux; c'est plus "politiquement correct". L'option avec le "et" est donc la bonne dans ce contexte.

Comment: Personnellement, j'opterais pour "à tous et toutes." Ça sonne plus naturel.

Comment: Mais pas utilisé, en raison de la courtoisie (malgré la parité)

Answer (score 5):

Plutôt

> Joyeuses Fêtes

tout court! implicitement à tous et à toutes.